# Return specific values based on return values of past query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**What i'm trying to do:**
I need to get the users online status based on other successful queries. The logic goes like this: (1). verify users are friends  (2).if they are proceed to obtain the users online friends. A boolean  represents if they are online or offline in the user_status col. in the users table.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id bigserial UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(70),
username VARCHAR(30)UNIQUE,
dob  INTEGER,
country VARCHAR(30),
province VARCHAR(30),
city VARCHAR(30),
user_status BOOLEAN
date TIMESTAMP
);

   CREATE TABLE relationships(
record bigserial UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
user_one_id bigserial REFERENCES users(user_id),
user_two_id bigserial REFERENCES users(user_id),
relationship_status INTEGER,
date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME zone
)
```

**What I have so far and what it does:**

```
SELECT user_one_id, user_two_id, relationship_status 
FROM relationships 
  FULL OUTER JOIN users 
               ON users.user_id = relationships.user_one_id 
               OR users.user_id = relationships.user_two_id 
WHERE users.user_id = 3 
  AND relationships.relationship_status = 1
```

The number 3 is simply a placeholder for X user. relationship_status = 1 means that if the value of 1 is present in the row it means they are friends. This query I have currently returns all the friends between user_id (3)  that's where I am currently and this is where I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the join query:

`users.user_id = relationships.user_one_id AND users.user_id = relationships.user_two_id`

replace `OR` with `AND`.

This is the first mistake I guess. Let me know if the issue is still there.

Comment: that does not return what is expected the original query returned the relationships with no issues. I'm more or less curious how to utilise a different query structure or build on the one provided to (1) check if theyre friends (2) see if their friends are online. The two tables I provided should be adequate